# XML file is processed incorrectly when using REST service on JBoss 7.5.0

Tags: java, xml, rest, jboss, character-encoding

We use JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA to deploy our application.

We have a method for REST service that is defined as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
Response createTest(Test test, @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

`Test` is the class that is used for mapping of incoming xml file.

Incoming XML files are saves as "ISO-8859-1" files and inside them we define encoding as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
```

With "regular" characters everything works fine, the issues start when we have `äöü` in xml.
In this case when REST method is called we have an exception

```
ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (http-/172.28.105.3:443-6) RESTEASY000100: Failed executing POST /test: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:147) [resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:106) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:109) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:160) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
```

We've tried multiple ways to resolve this issue:

**1) Changed method signature so xml is received as String and then unmarshall it ourselves instead of relying on JBoss :**

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
Response createTest(String xml, @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

In this case we receive xml file as String but `äöü` are replaced with ���. Please note that next changes we tried with this method.

**2) Set system properties in standalone.xml as follows:**

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

No result. There is ��� instead of `äöü`.

**3) Change standalone.conf**

Set `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Still no result.

**4) Change annotation for xml file**

```
@Consumes("application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

In this case - Unsupported Media Type

**5) Change encoding in incoming xml files to UTF-8 and save them as UTF-8.**

In this case everything works as expected. But it's preferable to keep xml files in ISO-8859-1, because it will require many efforts to change the workflow.

Can anyone give a hint what we can try next? I'm sure there must be a way fix it for ISO-8859-1.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up changing signature of service method: instead of String we pass array of bytes

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
Response createTest(byte[] xml, @Context UriInfo uriInfo);
```

And then creating String object ourselves:

```
String xmlAsString = new String(xml, "ISO-8859-1");
```